# How to make clickable parent link accordion menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation, accordion

How to make clickable parent dropdown(accordion menu) link on mobile. When I click to parent  link, only the drilldown or accordion menu toggle, bu the lparent link not clickable. I use foundation zurb 6.

```
<ul data-accordion-menu class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="parent.html">should be clickable on mobile</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would like to do that, but you could use some JavaScript to accomplish this goal.

```
$(document).on('click', '.is-accordion-submenu-parent', function (e) {
    if (Foundation.MediaQuery.is('small only')) {
        var $submenu = $(this).children('[data-submenu]');
        if ($submenu.length) {
            $submenu.remove();
            location.href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
        }
    }
});
```

This code will trigger only for small screen sizes because of this line:

```
if (Foundation.MediaQuery.is('small only'))
```

It will remove the submenu from the DOM (you don't need it anyway since you're being redirected to another page) and redirect you to the page located in the parent's `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
var wdata = [];
$(document).on('click', '.is-accordion-submenu-parent > a', function (e) {
    if (Foundation.MediaQuery.is('small only')) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href'),
            date = new Date(),
            diff = date - wdata.parentClickDate;
        if (wdata.parentHref == href && diff < 1000) {
            window.location.href = href
        }
        wdata.parentHref = href;
        wdata.parentClickDate = date;
    }
});
```

Comment: redirect to page if you click on parent two times in 1s